# How to stop Loop If current cell selection is empty?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I want to stop my loop if the current selection is empty. I have tried the following:

```
If (IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet3").ActiveCell)) Then Exit Do

If Sheets("Sheet3").Selection.Value = "" Then Exit Do ;tried to replace "" with Empty and Nothing but didn't work either

If Sheets("Sheet3").Activecell.Value is Empty Then Exit Do

If Sheets("Sheet3").Selection is blank Then Exit Do
```

The issue is if I don't stop the loop somehow it will carry on forever.

I was hoping somebody can help me here.

**EDIT :**

This is my code:

```
Public Sub CopyFilteredData()

  Do
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$25239") _
      .AutoFilter _
        Field:=5, _
        Criteria1:=Sheets("Sheet3").Application.Selection.Value
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "+"
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ' This is where the code to stop the loop needs to go
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess the problem is not exiting the loop, but the selection in your code never changed.

Comment: The selection is always moving down and that is the criteria of my filter. The problem is that it won't stop with these option even if the cell is empty.

Comment: `ActiveCell` is an independent object, not belongs to any worksheet. Try `If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then Exit Do`. However I suggest do not use `Selection` nor `ActiveCell` in your code, use their address and access them by `.Value` directly would be better.

Comment: I have just tried it, didn't work. The macro won't stop if it hits the empty cell.

Comment: Are you always selecting more than one cell or sometimes cell selection is just one cell? Will selection always be single column or it could be multicolumn?

Comment: Are you sure your `ActiveCell` is moving on? I've tried, it works perfectly.

Comment: Sheets("Sheet4").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$25239").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    Sheets("Sheet3").Application.Selection.Value
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet5").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "+"
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then Exit Do

And this between DO and LOOP

Comment: Shrivallabha Redij - My selection will always be a single cell moving down in column A one by one until it hits an empty cell.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `If IsEmpty` line and check the code ever executed or not. BTW, after my testing, the `Criteria1` part may cause the problem. Even you called `Sheets("Sheet3")`, the `Selection` is still in your `Sheets("Sheet4")`

Comment: If you are posting extra code for your question, please edit it into the body of the question. Don't add it in a comment. I have done the edit for you this time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a classic case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

#### Y Solution

The main reason none of your four attempts to detect an empty cell work, is a lack of understanding on what `Selection` and `ActiveCell` actually are. They are properties of the `Application` object and return the following

- `Selection` - the selected object **of the active sheet** (the top most sheet)
- `ActiveCell` - the active cell **of the active sheet** (the top most sheet)

You can't use `Sheets("Sheet3").ActiveCell` or `Sheets("Sheet3").Selection` as the `Sheet` object doesn't have these properties.

What you *can* use is `Application.ActiveCell` and `Application.Selection` or, more simply, `ActiveCell` and `Selection`. Of course, this will only work after activating `Sheet3`.

My preferred way of doing this is:

```
Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
If (IsEmpty(ActiveCell)) Then Exit Do
```

Your code also contains a similar problem with this bit:

```
Criteria1:=Sheets("Sheet3").Application.Selection.Value
```

While the code correctly gets the `Selection` object, it doesn't actually activate `Sheet3` and is exactly the same as writing:

`Criteria1:=Application.Selection.Value` or `Criteria1:=Selection.Value`

Fixing this issue by storing the `Sheet3` selection value in a variable leads to the following working code:

```
Option Explicit
'(v0.2)
Public Sub Y_Fixed_BUT_VERY_VERY_VERY_BAD_CODE()

  ' Added three lines and changed a fourth to fix the incorrect usage of "Selection" for the criteria
  ' Changed a fifth line to add the correct loop exit code
  Sheets("Sheet3").Activate ' Fix#1 Not necessary if the code is always run from Sheet3
  Dim varSheet3ActiveCellValue As Variant ' Fix#2
  Do
    varSheet3ActiveCellValue = ActiveCell.Value2 ' Fix#3
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$R$25") _
      .AutoFilter _
        Field:=5, _
        Criteria1:=varSheet3ActiveCellValue ' Fix#4
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "+"
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select ' Fix#5
    If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then Exit Do
  Loop

End Sub
```

---

#### X Solution

As mentioned in response to your first posted question, you really, *really* need to learn how to avoid using `.Select`. [This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) is a good place to start.

The following code is the equivalent to the above, **without using a single `.Select`, `.Activate`, `Selection`, or `ActiveCell`**. It also includes a better way to find the last value in a column. (Your method fails unless there is a least one cell containing a value after the first cell.)

A useful way to work out how the code works is to select a word in it, for example `With` and pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>. This will bring up the Excel Help related to that word, with explanations and examples.

```
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <in any standard module>
' Version    : 1.0
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : N/A
' Source     : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47468132/1961728
'============================================================================================
Option Explicit

Public Sub X__GOOD_CODE()

  Dim rngFilterCriteriaList As Range
  With Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A3")
    Set rngFilterCriteriaList = Range(.Cells(1), .EntireColumn.Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  End With
  Dim rngCell As Range
  For Each rngCell In rngFilterCriteriaList
    Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:R25239") _
      .AutoFilter _
        Field:=Range("E:E").Column, _
        Criteria1:=rngCell.Value2
    Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _
      Destination:=Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A:A").Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A:A").Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value2 = "+"
  Next rngCell
  Sheets("Sheet4").Cells.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: Just came back from holiday and read through your answer, it looks brilliant, I will try it as soon as I can!

Comment: @K.Robert Thanks. Was wondering where you had got to. I've left out a few details as I didn't want the post to get *too* long. Let me know if you think I need to add any more explanations.

Comment: Just tried it, works brilliantly, thanks very much you have saved me a lot of time with this!

Answer (score -1):

selection can contain 1 or more cells. If you want to check if all the cells in the selection are empty you can use the worksheet function countblank which returns the number of empty cells. If the number of empty cells in the selection equals the number of cells in the selection then all the cells in the selection are empty. your test can be adapted like this

```
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Selection) = Selection.Count Then Exit Do
```

Answer (score -1):

if u cannot specify the range then have to activated sheet3 then its works refer below:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
If ActiveCell = "" Then
Exit Do
End If
```

Comment: Is it any different to Sheets("Sheet3").Select what I already do?

Comment: @K.Robert  The `Sheets` object is a parent object for Worksheets and Chart Sheets. If a workbook has 3 worksheets and 1 chart sheet, `sheets' function will count 4 sheets but `worksheets` will count 3 three sheets

Comment: Ashok (& @K.Robert) In other words, no.  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate` and `Sheets("Sheet3").Select` behave exactly the same in this situation

Comment: @robinCTS - here sheets and worksheets both working same but i am elaborate what the difference between those two objects

Comment: Who gave the devote for above ans - may know reason pls?

Comment: @robinCTS  May be but developer should understand what is the purpose of using function,object etc..

Comment: I realise that. However, if we are taking about supplying irrelevant info, you forgot to mention the difference between the `ThisWorkbook` object and the `Application` object. What you didn't do is *actually answer* K.Robert's question, which, I repeat, is "no".

Comment: As for why the downvote, my guess is that the other 3 short answers are very low quality (irrelevant/don't actually answer the question) and your answer *looks* like it might be too. Somebody saw this and decided to downvote them all. Your answer is correct but, as the wording is hard to understand it is easy to mistake it for low quality. (I realise this is not your fault, as I don't think English is your first language.)

Answer (score -1):

Your selection will not change if you are not changing the cell by using `.select` in the code and therefore will likely result in infinite loop. But using `.select` in the code is not considered as good practice as it slows down the process.

I'd suggest using `For...each` Loop like below.

```
Dim rng as Range
For each rng in selection
    If Len(rng.Value) = 0 then Exit Sub '\\ Exit at first blank cell
    '\\ Do process here
Next rng
```

Comment: I am definitely changing the cell with the offset.Select code. I do know it is not ideal however couldn't figure out how to make it work with the Dim and as version, I've only got into VBA :).

Answer (score -2):

Your solution is [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/309207-stop-macro-if-cell-empty.html).
Credits to mvptomlinson from MrExcel.com

The right code is

```
'Your code to loop through copying sheets
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
'Your code to continue if A1 isn't empty
```

Comment: It cannot be a specific range though, it needs to be the value of my current selection which I have tried as you can see above. I have tested your code by all means with replacing .Range with .Selection but didn't work.